# MyBatis NumberFormatException while executing query

Tags: java, mybatis

Using MyBatis, I have a SQL that receives as parameter the String `"fr.id_lotacao in (3007, 3008, 3009, 3010)"`

SQL:

```
...
<if test="idLotacao != -1">
    and ${idLotacao}
</if>
...
```

I call from Java this way:

```
getDB1SqlSessionTemplate().selectList("sql", MyBatisUtil.createMap("idLotacao", getIdsLotacao(lotacao)));
```

Where `getIdsLotacao(lotacao)` returns the String passed as parameter.

But, when executed, MyBatis throws the error:

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 

### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "fr.id_lotacao in (3007, 3008, 3009, 3010)"
```

When receiving the parameter with $, isn't MyBatis supposed to replace `${idLotacao}` with the String `"fr.id_lotacao in (3007, 3008, 3009, 3010)"`?

What am I doing wrong? What's causing this error?

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes, even if you're comparing strings, and your parameter is also a String, Mybaits return a NFE.

To solve this, you have to replace the following expression:

```
<if test="parameter =='A'"> 
AND YOURCOLUMN IS NOT NULL 
</if>
```

for this:

```
<if test="parameter eq 'A'.toString()"> 
AND YOURCOLUMN IS NOT NULL 
</if>
```

Comment: I had this problem, so thanks for the idea, but it didn't work for me. Instead I just did a parameter += parameter before calling the function and then checked if parameter == 'AA' instead

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem described by Aitor and resolved it a different way.  I think it's trying to do a numeric comparison because it's parsing 'A' as a char.

So I swapped the single quotes and double quotes to ensure it is being parsed as a String.

```
<if test='parameter =="A"'> 
AND YOURCOLUMN IS NOT NULL 
</if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are comparing a string with a number ie -1,which is causing number format exception.
Put -1 in quotes like '-1' to make it work